# KEYCODE_BACK doesn't work when pressed for the very first time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having trouble overriding the Back Button press on Android.

The thing is, everything works perfectly except for the very first time.
When I load the app and press the back button for the first time, it pauses the app, which is NOT what I want. Other than that, it works as expected.

My code:

```
private void setupDeviceButtons(){ // this is ran at the very beginning (onViewCreated())
        // setting up a listener to close the menus when the back button is pressed
        View view = getView();

        Log.e(TAG, "This happens when I load the app" );

        if (view != null) {

            Log.e(TAG, "This also happens when I load the app");

            view.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "But this doesn't happen when I press the back button for the first time.");

                    // we filter all actions that are not key down
                    if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        return true;

                    ...

                }
                return false;
            });
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR on setupDeviceButtons(): Unable to set back button behaviour. View is null.");
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you override `onKeyDown` in your activity instead `onKeyListener` in a view?

Comment: That was my first approach. It's a good idea. But it's good practice to isolate the code.

Comment: But it will help you to reduce some work around. Like, suppose you set `onKeyListener` for one view but another view of your layout currently in focused state, in that case your key event code might not work.

Comment: And I think that's exactly what was happening since Maraj Hussain's answer works very well. I understand your point of view. But I would rather do a small workaround than to have spaghetti code in my function. It's just a matter of opinion though. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code working perfectly in fragments.

```
    //on fragment back pressed
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK  && event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
               // do your code on back pressed
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```